# Filter Records from buttonclick event

Tags: filter

I have searched everywhere for an answer, but because I am so new to programming I don't have a real grasp of the tech language used to describe the procedure. I have probably seen the answer, but didn't recognize it as an answer.

Basically I have a database displayed in a grid. I have a name field (teacher name) and I want to find all the records that have that name, in the teacher name field in their records. In other words I would like to find all the people who were taught by Teacher X.

I am using a TDBEdit to display the teacher name field. What I would like to do is to use a button click to filter all the records based on the text displayed in the DBEdit.

I can search all the fields using a filter dialog now. I would like not to execute a dialog in this search and I don't know where to start.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is what I came up with:

```
procedure TForm1.btnSearchClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
tblTest.Filter:='Teacher='+QuotedSTR(Edit1.Text);
tblTest.Filtered:=True;
end;
```

Then to refresh the table I used another button click event:

```
procedure TForm1.btnRestoreClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
tblTest.Filtered:=False;
end;
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: For future reference, the reason noone answered you because you didn't  say which environment/language you were talking about, so the question was ignored. The tags field should indicate this info - the word "filter" isn't useful.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I will keep that in mind. I don't think that I have enough points to create my own tag. I had to choose from a list of choices presented